# how do I fix this error in python 3.3? TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was trying to create a number guessing game but I get the error for "guessestaken"I copied the code from http://inventwithpython.com/IYOCGwP_book1.pdf page 57.Sorry I am a bit new to python.

```
import random
guessestaken=0
print ("hello what ur name?")
myname=input()
number=random.randint(1,20)
print ("well " + myname + " i am thinking of a number guess it")

while guessestaken < 6 :
    guessestaken=guessestaken+1
    guess =input('take a guess')
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess <number:
        print('too low')
    if guess >number:
        print ('too high')
    if guess ==number:
        break
    if guess ==number:
        guessestaken=str(guessestaken)
        print ('good job ' + myname + ' you are right!')
        print ('you guessed it in ' + guessestaken + ' guesses')
    if guess !=number:
        guessestaken = str(guessestaken)
        print ("I am sorry but you couldn't get it right")
        print ("you couldn't guess it in " + guessestaken + " guesses")
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is (trying to) inform you that you're trying to compare a `str` with an `int`. In particular, there should be a traceback informing you of where the error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    while guessestaken < 6 :
```

You can see that you explicitly convert `guessestaken` to a string:

```
guessestaken = str(guessestaken)
```

Which is clearly not necessary. When you want to print the number of guesses taken, either do it inline using `+` (which is not recommended or "pythonic") or use `format`:

```
print('you guessed it in ' + str(guessestaken) + ' guesses')
print('You guessed it in {} guesses'.format(guessestaken))
```

Comment: "... either do it inline or use `format`"? I'd rather say "either use `format` or the `%` operator, or just pass three arguments to `print`, but stop concatenating strings by hand...

Answer (score 3):

You are converting `guesstaken` to string to display it

```
guessestaken=str(guessestaken)
```

and then `while` loop checks whether

```
while guessestaken < 6 :
```

which causes type error (python cannot compare **string** and **int**). 
You should simply use other name for the string or do it inline using python constructs like

```
print('You guessed it in {} guesses'.format(guessestaken))
```

Comment: Downvote... there's two good methods of string formating in python, concatenating strings isn't one of them. And in this example you could even pass the three values as separate arguments to `print`. There's not a single reason to call `str` here.

Comment: this completely not related to the problem, yet valuable comment, thanks